# Need to plot the values on bar graph axis in custom order

Tags: visualforce, google-charts

On bar graph in google charts want to plot the axis values in custom order. Right now they are plotting from highest to lowest, how to plot custom names on axis, any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: var data = new google.visualization.Table();
                data.addColumn('string', 'project');
                data.addColumn('number', '# of clients');
                data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
                data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
                 for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){

Comment: var r = result[i]; 
                    if (r.RowType == 'ProjByClient') {
                        if(r.project=="" || r.Project==null) r.Project="Unknown";
 data.addRow([r.Project, r.TotalClients,r.TotalClients,"Net Value is: $"+(r.GrossValue).formatMoney(0)]);
                    }
                }       var options = {
                    title: '# of Clients by Projects',
                    displayAnnotations: true,

Comment: width: 720,
                    height: 500,
      legend:{position: "none"},                    
        vAxis: {
                    title:'Project Count',
                    format: 'short',
                    minValue:0, maxValue:3,
                   }
                };
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                chart.draw(data, options);